# Does this form of differential equation always result in a vertical asymptote?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that f(z) is a strictly increasing function (with real input and output and no root) for which there exists some positive (real) value of b such that it asymptotically outgrows $z^{b+1}$ for positive z.

Is it true that any solution to $$  \frac{dy}{dx} = f(y) $$ will contain a vertical asymptote providing y (real) exceeds $0$ at some point?

Conversely, is such a vertical asymptote impossible given that $z^{b+1}$ outgrows $f(z)$?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, then definitely no for the first question. Take $f(z)=z^1$, we have that $y=C\cdot e^x$, which has no vertical asymptote.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I meant 1+ b where b would   be 0, not positive.

Comment: If $f$ has a root, then the corresponding constant solution will not have an asymptote. You need either that $f$ has no root or have to amend "any".

Comment: I think the best course of action for question 2 (and for the updated version of question 1) is looking at the Gronwall Inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality and trying to adapt its proof for this case

Comment: For instance, in Corollary 2.2 of https://acadsol.eu/caa/19/4/15

Comment: Thank you, it looks rather complicated . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The central computation is not that complicated. Set $u=y^{-b}$, then $$u'=-by^{-b-1}y'=-b·\frac{f(y)}{y^{1+b}}.$$ Show that $y$ grows above all bounds, which needs $y_0>0$ and $f(y_0)>0$; then at some point $u'<-b$, which ensures that $u$ reaches a root in finite time. This root of $u$ is a singularity for $y$.

The assumptions do not cover at all what the situation is for $f(y_0)<0$.